# CakePHP customize select box

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Controller:

```
$products=$this->Product->find('list',
                               array(
                                  'conditions' => array('Product.publish'=>1),
                                  'order' => array('Product.publish_order ASC')
                               ));
$this->set('products',$products);
```

View:

```
echo $form->input('product',array('options' =>$products));
```

Look at this example:

```
<select>
  <option value="cars" disabled>Cars</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Option `Cars` is disabled because i would like to use it as a category content.
I need such thing in my CakePHP app How can i do this?

Comment: Is 'Cars' coming in $products ?

Comment: No, is there another way to put it in?

Comment: have you referred [cakephp cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select)

Answer (score 0):

[Source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select)

```
$options = array(
   'Cars' => $products
);
echo $this->Form->select('product', $options);
```

OR

```
echo $this->Form->select('product', array('Cars' => $products));
```

You have used `$form` here so you can change `$this->Form` to `$form`